# Count the value of columns?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called msgs. I also have a column called phrase. How it looks is that each row contains a different number for instance

```
id|phrase
---------
1|270
2|100
3|50
4|2
5|0
```

How do I count phrase altogether? The total of these numbers is 422 (counted with the calculator) how do I count it out using MySQL?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-sum-function.htm

Comment: SELECT SUM(`phrase`) AS total FROM `msgs`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(phrase) AS nb_phrases FROM my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) as count from msgs
```

will count number of results in `msgs` table, in this case it will return `5`

```
select sum(phrase) as sum from msgs
```

will sum all values from `phrase` column in `msg` table, in this case it will return `422`